# Changing font color of menu item if this item has background

Tags: javascript, css, menu, navigation, menuitem

I create a new site on this domain keksik.com
Here you can see navigation menu at the top.

The problem is that I need the font color of active menu item to be black even when it is not hovered. And the same thing should be applied to parent menu item when I hover on the child item.

So, I think I need to use javascript here to change font color to black dynamically if the menu item has background image.

I tried to add this code to head, but nothing changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(#top #nav li).css('background') == 'url(images1/mtbg.gif) no-repeat left center') {
    $(#top #nav li a).css('color', 'black');
  }  

});
</script>
```

So, I hope you can help me with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think actually you should put some kind of active class on the appropriate link and its parent... if you can.

Comment: the problem is that when I hover any menu item, white color changes to black, but if the item is not hovered but still has background, white stays white, though I need it to stay black.

Comment: what prevent you from using proper css definitions for :hover, :active ?

Comment: vittore, there is no problem with hover - it works as it should work.
And there is no problem with active, but if I change the font of active menu Item in css to be black, the font stays black all the time, even if this item does not have background. So I need a solution to change font to black dinamically if the item has background. I think it is possible via javascript.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't see my comment earlier, but you should change the background string, and update to jquery 1.7..  1.3 is very old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm..  not sure I understand, but maybe something like this would work:

```
var strBG = "url(images1/mtbg.gif) no-repeat left center";
$("#top #nav li a").live("hover", function(){
    if ($(this).parent().css("background") == strBG)
    {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
        $(this).parent().css("color", "black");
    }
});
$("#top #nav li").live("hover", function(){
    if ($(this).css("background") == strBG)
    {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
        $(this).find("a").css("color", "black");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution looks good.
I inserted this code before /head tag. but it does not work. Please, check if i inserted it correctly.

I will try to explain what I need.When you open keksik.com the first menu item has background and whie font,but it should be black(without hovering).And font color of first item should be white when I hover another menu item. The same thing happens when I hover third menu item and then hover it's child -the font color of parent should stay black, not switch to white. In any case there is background under text -it should be black, where there is no background -white.

Comment: Please do 2 things:
1) Make sure you call this jquery file: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2) the background is this: 'url("../images1/mtbgo.gif") repeat-x scroll left top transparent'

3) I added a better solution for you.. please see if it fits you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but why can't you just use this:

```
#top #nav li.active, 
#top #nav li.active:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

What's wrong with that?